# When using vim with screen the keys ctrl + right and ctrl + left don't work

Tags: gnu-screen, vim

In the last days i became very addicted of using the combination terminator (in full screen) + screen + vim. But i'm having problems with the ctrl + right and ctrl + left key mappings, they are erasing text instead of jumping words. I already checked and it works as expected when using only terminator and vim.

Somebody know how to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's probably due to `TERM` being set to `screen`. If using bash, try:

```
export TERM=xterm
```

before running vim.

Note this might have other consequences, so you might want to try other terminals if that's the case.

Comment: Tks, it works like a charm

Comment: Nice, glad it worked fine for you!

Comment: Thanks; I really wanted to use byobu in ubunut, but these issues just made it frustrating.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `:set term=xterm` inside of vim